# NHibernated Generated Select Query has Too Many Projections

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate, criteria-api

I have an NHibernate detached criteria query which has a couple of inner joins, and when I get its generated SQL statement it seems to have a lot of columns in the projection which I don't actually need. The most annoying thing is this makes a significant performance  impact.

for instance a generated query may look like

```
    select a.a, a.b, a.c .... a.z,
    b.a, b.b, b.c .... b.z
    from ...
    where...
```

But what I am actually trying to get at is

```
    select a.*
    from ...
    where...
```

I have tried to locate any resources that might help me solve this by using result transformers or other methods since I my knowledge on the criteria api is quite immature.

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  query.SetProjection(ResultProjectionList);
  query.SetResultTransformer(NHibernate.Transform.Transformers.AliasToBean(typeof(Result)));
```

Worked like a charm :-)

Also this article helped a lot

http://www.skimedic.com/blog/post/2009/02/03/Using-Projections-and-Transformers-in-NHibernate.aspx

Answer (score 1):

It is not considered best practice to select * on databases. You will find endless comments referencing that. So rather avoid the select *. You can use projections in NHibernate using QueryOver or Linq syntax and generate only the SQL select for columns you need.

```
           var trades = _session.QueryOver<Trade>()
              .SelectList(list => list
                                        .Select(x => x.Name))
              .List<object>();
```

or

```
            var trades = _session.Query<Trade>()
                  .Select(x => new
                                     {
                                           x.Name
                                     })
                  .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for alerting me to this. But this wasn't the answer I expected :-)

Comment: I had issues with some properties not being properly loaded due to lazy loading when I used this approached. That's why I am using a custom dto and a result transformer.